# What happened to threadpool?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, c++11

Does anyone of you know what happened to [Threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/)?

It appears to be of good quality, although there are no tests included. Why has this not been added to Boost? Does anyone know of a C++11 port?

Comment: Has it ever even been formally considered for inclusion in Boost?

Comment: @Bart: I don't know. It's written to fit into Boost more or less but maybe it was never formally considered.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it was. It doesn't appear among their [list of reviewed components](http://www.boost.org/community/review_schedule.html) for example. But I don't have any more authoritative information than that. :)

Comment: @Manuel I think the author actually never got around "finishing" it to his complete satisfaction and therefore did not even propose it. I based my own [threadpool](https://bitbucket.org/KillianDS/sak/src/a9168435da51/sak/threadpool.h) on `boost.Threadpool`, which is c++11 but of course only verified against my immediate needs.

Comment: @KillianDS If you post this as an answer, I'd mark it as accepted. I think the other answer by Steve M is not correct.

Comment: There is this library as a simple thread pooling library -> https://code.google.com/p/threadpool11/

Answer (score 2):

[Boost::Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.threadgroup) has a `thread_group` type that provides typical thread pool operations. In C++11, using `std::future`s, will potentially do some pooling automatically.

Comment: does `thread_group` provide scheduling operations on the pool level? Also, I think you still have to provide your own logic to "reuse" a thread to execute multiple functions. Far from a full functional thread-pool imho.

Comment: Also I don't think pooling is really realistic for `std::async` (I assume you mean that specifically as `std::future` does no launching on its own). It would be quite a waste of the stdlib to always launch N threads statically. But it can't limit the number of threads in such a threadpool either (blocking recursive async calls are allowed afaik). So you'll end up with a dynamic threadpool with 0 initial threads and unlimitied maximum threads, which is almost equal to no threadpool at all :P

Comment: @KillianDS: I'm not sure what you mean by "launch N threads statically." The MSVC stdlib async/futures will pool threads based on the system's number of cores, rather than a thread for each task (reference: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/STL11-Magic-Secrets).

Comment: as far as I read his slides correct (I don't have 55m to spare), microsoft's implementation could fail exactly on what I mention. If you don't create a thread for each `async` call, you can get a dead-lock. See the example on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async), if you only launch a specific number of threads, this may never finish. So you have to be able to increase the pool. Also, creating a default thread pool for `async` calls doesn't break anything, it's potentially just a waste of threads.

Comment: @SteveM: Am I missing something or is KillianDS right in that thread_group does not offer "fire and forget" launching of tasks?

Comment: @Manuel: Yeah, that looks to be the case. I thought thread_group did some pooling but it really is just a group of threads.

Comment: @KillianDS: That example will finish even if the pool is limited to just one thread.

Comment: @SteveM: how? Note that the one thread will block in the return statement on `handle.get()`. How will any other `async` call finish, when the one thread it can use is blocked?

Comment: @KillianDS: Oops, I messed up my thoughts on that and am wrong. Sorry about that one. On the Microsoft part, I'll have to try it out later and see what it really does.